# Symfony 3.4 console command definition not being recognized

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm upgrading a existing Symfony 3.3 application to Symfony 3.4.

I'm getting a console command auto-registration warning in spite of the fact that I've defined the command in the bundle's services.yml file. The warning:

> [2017-12-14 12:22:19] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Auto-registration of
>   the command "Dplh\DplhIssuesBundle\Command\IssuesReportCommand" is
>   deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4
>   based service discovery instead.

The entry in Dplh/DplhIssuesBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
  Dplh\DplhIssuesBundle\Command\IssuesReportCommand:
    public:   true
    tags:     ['console.command']
    calls:
      - [ saveDependencies, [ '@logger' ]]
```

I am positive that the services.yml file is being processed by Symfony because if I intentionally create a syntax error in it, Symfony reports that the file contains invalid YAML.

Comment: Move it out of the `Command` directory? (If you're still using 3.4, it'll find those in there and complain.)

Comment: I have other private bundles that have Command directories with the commands defined in their services.yml files and Symfony doesn't complain about them.

Comment: Alright, if you don't want to move it out the way, you need to give the command a name so that lazy loading can actually happen: `tags: { name: 'console.command', command: 'issues:report' }`. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html

Comment: Okay. Added $defaultName to the command source. Changed the tag to include both name: and command:. Exact same result. Besides, there is still the question of why it doesn't complain about the commands in other bundles.

Comment: Straw-grasping: dump-autoload (theory: the other bundles were properly configured on first pass, this one is not -- needing correction (done) and cache reset (pending dump-autoload)).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "dump-autoload". Do you mean delete the var/cache/dev directory and do a console cache:warmup? If so, I did that. same results.

Comment: Effectively, yes. I am now out of ideas. I'd suggest creating a new bundle, copying in just the smallest set possible, and attempt to identify the specific thing holding it back. My guess is, it's something small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it.
There was a reference to the Dplh\DplhIssuesBundle\Command\IssuesReportCommand class in another bundle's services.yml file (copy/paste error, I'm sure).

Removing that reference removed the error.